# Best way to automatically link Gene Entrez ID with Gene Symbol in TCGA

Tags: genetics, cancer, tcga

I am trying to figure out how to link Gene Entrez ID with Gene Symbol, for TCGA dataset.

So far, I have found [this ftp directory](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/DATA) with Gene info updated daily.

But, for Entrez ID 728661, I have found two different mappings:

- [here](http://bioinformatics.picr.man.ac.uk/adapt/ProbeToGeneAction.adapt?genes=728661) symbol is RP11-345P4.4;
- [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=728661), and in gene info downloaded from ftp above, symbol is SLC35E2B while RP11-345P4.4 is in the field 'locus tag'.

Since I am a newbie I am bit confused about this thing. And, while I think they can be synonyms, I need to know if there is a best practice to use in this case, and if I need to implement some script on my own to do it automatically.

Thanks

Comment: To be sure, if I understand you right: You want to have a list with the Gene ID in one column and the corresponding Gene symbol in the next?

Comment: It is best to use the Standard Gene Symbol (HGNC) or Refseq IDs. Some Refseq IDs may be of this form `NM_xxxx.x` (*where x is a number*). In such cases remove the `.` and the following number. Sometimes same transcript can have more than one refseq ids- in such cases use the shorter id (not a universal rule though).

Comment: @Chris yes, I want the unique mapping between the two ID, is it possible?

Comment: @WYSIWYG Thanks, I think I am going to use the HGNC symbol. Could you please explain, if you know it, why the two symbols differs? HGNC is the standard   for Gene Symbols? Thanks

Comment: Do you have this list with the IDs? If so, you can use Biomart from Ensembl to convert it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it as soon as possible. Could you please write that as answer? So if it works I can vote it and accept it..